# Handle 2 types of number format using culture if possible

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, number-formatting, currency-formatting

Currently i've a following Scenario :

I've a custom control for Numeric Input. Which have the Property called : DecimalType. Which might be Long or Short Decimal.

And, the Problem is : I want to Format the Given input as Common. Which either format the Current input in 2 decimal Digits (Short) or 4 decimal Digits(Long) by using the Current Culture.

I can setup only one format on the Current Culture.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
```

or

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 4;
```

So, in my situation, how do i handle this **efficiently**? Because, in a single form there might be 2 short decimal textboxes and 4 long decimal textboxes. By changing **NumberDecimalDigits** to 2 will not work for long decimal or vice-versa.

**In Short :** The Text should be formatted according to the Current Culture with the 2 custom decimal length.

Any suggestions that i can follow to handle those things?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here. (1) use an explicit [custom number format pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the number of decimal digits -- something like #,0.00 and #,0.0000 -- or (2) don't rely on the CurrentCulture at all. All the formatting functions allow you to explicitly provide a CultureInfo object so you can have one for each.

Personally, I would use option 1.